# How to Use LINQ to Select List of KeyValuePairs By Matching Key and Values

Tags: c#, .net

I have a generic list of List of KeyValuePair,

i.e. `List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>`.

I am trying to extract an internal List `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

based on the value of the Key and Values.

Here is my code:

```
            var layer =
            (from item in layers
            from kvp in item
            where kvp.Key == "category" && kvp.Value == category_name
            where kvp.Key == "featureType" && kvp.Value == feature_type
            where kvp.Key == "assetType" && kvp.Value == asset_type
            select item);`
```

In the code above item will have a List of KeyValuePairs and I want to match those to find the right item.

What I am trying to say in my where clauses is where a KeyValuePair (KVP) has a key == "category" and the value of that KVP == category_name and also where another KVP has a key == "featureType" and the value of that KVP is feature_type and yet another KVP has a key = "assetType" and the value of that KVP == asset_type.

This is not working as layer is an empty list but I know the item that has the matches for the three KVP's is there.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: If `item` is a single `KeyvaluePair`, how could it match all three conditions? The key cannot be category,featureType and assetType at the same type. What do you want to select, what is your desired result?

Comment: An item will have three KeyValuePairs, a "Category" KVP a "FeatureType" KVP and a AssetType" KVP. So I need to find the one item whose collection of KVP's match the variables. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You could just replace the second and third `where` with `and` and it will work.

Comment: Good answer findeberg - it seems obvious now that you said that!

Comment: Sorry findeberg, I checked that out and it doesn't work after all. Did you check that before you posted? If so can I see how you did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is what you want, all lists which contain those key-value pairs:

```
IEnumerable<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> layer = layers
    .Where(l => l.Any(kv => kv.Key == "category" && kv.Value == category_name)
            &&  l.Any(kv => kv.Key == "featureType" && kv.Value == feature_type)
            &&  l.Any(kv => kv.Key == "assetType" && kv.Value == asset_type));
```

If you expect only one use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or (if it's not exceptional) [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).